# postfix virtual mailbox and forwards

Tags: linux, postfix

I setup postfix to run with virtual mailbox setup:

```
virtual_mailbox_domains = domaina.com domainb.com domainc.com
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/mail/virtualhosts
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox
virtual_minimum_uid = 500
virtual_uid_maps = static:500
virtual_gid_maps = static:12
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

/etc/postfix/virtual:

```
postmaster@domaina.com postmaster
postmaster@domainb.com postmaster
postmaster@domainc.com postmaster
```

/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox

```
first.account@domaina.com domaina.com/first.account
second.account@domainb.com domainb.com/second.account
@domainb.com domainb.com/catch-all
@domaina.com domaina.com/catch-all
@domainc.com domainc.com/catch-all
```

My question is; where should I set aliases for existing user accounts, forwarding to another email address or piping to a local file? For example; I want to set these three:

```
pipe@domaina.com /var/my_app/pipe_a.php
pipe@domainb.com /var/my_app/pipe_b.php
email@domainc.com domainc@gmail.com
email@domaina.com domaina@gmail.com
```

Should I set these in /etc/postfix/virtual or in /etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox file? I couldn't make them working.

Your help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found that pipes and aliases should be set in the `/etc/postfix/virtual` file.
Virtual mailbox users can be set under the `/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox` file.

Answer (score 0):

Postfix [pipes](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html) are configured in [main.cf](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html) as described in the manual.

Then you set [transport_maps](http://ww.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#transport_maps) to map (some) recipients to transports you defined (for pipeing).

Whereas delivering to [virtual users](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html) remains configured as usual.